# How does timestamp in TCP header work?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, tcpdump

I am a newbie to networking,I was analysing WireShark TCP dumps.I found TCP header timestamp value of 4016140 which dates back to 1970.Am i missing something?

Comment: Can you share the snapshot of wireshark tcp dumps that you are referring to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, but (TCP/)IP protocol related.

Answer (score 0):

TCP timestamps are reset to 0 on host reboot and incremented by OS dependent algorithm (for example it's incremented 100 times per sec [ref](http://marc.info/?l=intrusions&m=104356240325628&w=2) ), these are not based on host clock/wall time.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what @VenkatC said.  Note that standard (rfc1323) doesn't specify the unit of timestamp value. It's possible to measure the unit of timestamp this way: with Wireshark, capture a tcp session, look at the two packets sent by your PC, compare the difference between the wireshark timestamp and the difference between the TCP timestamp value field of the two packets.

In my case, the Wireshark timestamp difference is 160ms, the difference in TCP header timestamp values is 40.  So the unit is 4ms.  It may be different on your system.